# Query to find rows with nearest date in future

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to display a result set based on a min date value and today's date but can't seem to make it work. It's essentially a date sensitive price list.

Example Data

```
ID    Title    Value    ExpireDate
1     Fred      10       2019-03-01
2     Barney    15       2019-03-01
3     Fred2     20       2019-06-01
4     Barney2   25       2019-06-01
5     Fred3     30       2019-07-01
6     Barney3   55       2019-07-01
```

Required Results:
Display records based on minimum date > GetDate()

```
3     Fred2     20       2019-06-01
4     Barney2   25       2019-06-01
```

Any assistance would be great - thank you.

Comment: How do you get from input to output? What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried a straight forwards grouping - min(date) where Date > GetDate() ... but that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use where clause to filter all future rows and `row_number()` to find the first row per group:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Title ORDER BY ExpireDate) AS rn
    FROM t
    WHERE ExpireDate >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
) AS x
WHERE rn = 1
```

---

Based on your revised question, you can simply do this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM t
WHERE ExpireDate >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
ORDER BY ExpireDate
```

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't quite work. If you take a look back at the example data, there's a list of 6 dates, 2 have expired and 4 are available, it's the middle dates that I need - the minimum/lower dates which are after today.

Comment: There were some obvious typos, I have fixed and it returns row number 3 and 4: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2bf16/1

Comment: I see, thank you. I've not used Partition very often. Your code works if the Title's are the same across the various dates, but how would it work if the titles changed as the dates did, so for example,the first set would be 'Fred / Barney' - the 2nd set 'Fred2 / Barney2', the third set 'Fred3/Barney3'. ?

Comment: Then you have 4 future rows... how do you determine which two are needed? If you want all four then you need nothing except `ExpireDate >= CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)`

Comment: I guess that's where I was trying to go with my initial thoughts, based on minimum date. The code as is works, thanks very much for that - it gets me started, but to be a perfect fit, it would need to allow for changes in the title too.

Comment: You can always ask another question, but don't change the question after 21 hours.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm ahead of where I was which is great !

Comment: If you're interested in all `2019-06-01` records then remove `PARTITION BY Title`.